# How to get count with the 2 conditions inside ArrayList object Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let say I have this model class.

```
data class Bike(
    val bikeId: String? = null,
    val type: String? = null,
    val color: String? = null,
)
```

If I want to get the count for `color`, I can use this:-

```
val freqs = list.groupingBy { it.color }.eachCount()
```

Result will be:-

```
{GREEN=3, YELLOW=12}
```

How to get count where `type` also included?

Example result like:-

```
{MOUNTAIN and GREEN=2}
{FOLDING and GREEN=1}

{MOUNTAIN and YELLOW=5}
{FOLDING and YELLOW=1}
{BMX and YELLOW=6}
```

and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@broot's solution with `Pair` is probably sufficient in most cases.

If you need to pass this data around, a `Pair<String?, String?>` is not very informative about which component is which.
In that case, I would go for creating a proper class to represent that key for your grouping:

```kotlin
data class BikeCategory(val color: String?, val type: String?)

val freqs = list.groupingBy { BikeCategory(it.color, it.type) }.eachCount()
```

That are no more instances created in this solution than with the pairs, the difference is simply that these objects are more discoverable/readable when you use the map later on.

Depending on how you organize the code and use this result, you may want to also consider using a Map of Maps to represent these groupings:

```kotlin
val freqs = list.groupBy { it.color }.mapValues { (_, g) -> g.groupBy { it.type } }
```

Answer (score 3):

For each item you need to create a data object containing both fields. Simple `Pair` should be sufficient here:

```
list.groupingBy { it.type to it.color }.eachCount()
```

Just note `it.type to it.color` is basically the same as `Pair(it.type, it.color)`.